# Google Maps API scraping ALL places in an area

Tags: python, json, google-maps

I am trying to scrape all the "drugstore/pharmacy" in an area but I only get a limited number of them rather than ALL.

Is there anyway to get all the json data at once?

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
location = "33.589886, -7.603869"
radius = 26000
place_type = "pharmacy"
language = "fr"
r = requests.get(url + '&location=' +str(location)+'&radius='+str(radius) +   
'&type='+place_type+'&language='+language+'&key=' + api_key)
```

I only get 20 of them while I'd like to get the entirety of them in that radius.

Comment: The places API is limited to a maximum of 60 responses (in groups of 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses), the Places API returns up to 20 results:

> The Places API returns up to 20 establishment results per query

You should then use the `next_page_token` to spawn a new query and get the next page of results:

> `next_page_token` contains a token that can be used to return up to 20 additional results. A `next_page_token` will not be returned if there are no additional results to display. The maximum number of results that can be returned is 60. There is a short delay between when a `next_page_token` is issued, and when it will become valid.

Example:

```py
next_page_token = r.json().get('next_page_token')

while next_page_token:
    r = requests.get(url + '&pagetoken=' + next_page_token)

    # Parse the results page

    next_page_token = r.json().get('next_page_token')
```